# Add outdoor outlet opposite indoor outlet

Tags: electrical

sorry, this turns out to be a duplicate question already answered elswhere here

It would seem pretty easy to add an outdoor receptacle in the backyard if it would be allowed to be wired from an existing outlet in the dining room. If so, should I use a gfci receptacle or replace the breaker with a gfci breaker?

Comment: Is that dining room receptacle on one of the small appliance branch circuits?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use a GFCI outlet. It will be less expensive then replacing the breaker and why go into your panel if you don't have to. Use pigtails and not backstabs on your dining room outlet.

Don't forget the water resistant outlet cover. (see below)

[image]

Comment: Replace the dining room outlet with the GFCI, and wire the outdoor outlet to the LOAD terminals on the GFCI - it will last **much** longer than a GFCI located outside. Technically, I believe you should use a wet-rated wire (not NM cable) to connect to the outside outlet box - UF cable or conduit and THWN, for example.

Comment: @Ecnerwal  Excellent point.

Comment: I find WR weather rated GFCI’s last outside just as long as standard ones inside (the electronics are encased in plastic) if the box is within the wall NM cable is code compliant where it becomes a judgement of the AHJ is for surface mount. Some will allow direct surface mount and a very few will not. Any further than direct surface mount would not be code compliant unless allowed by the AHJ.+